# Looking for the most efficient method of pulling a count from a different table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables with the given number or rows in each.

```
Table         Rows     Purpose
product       1695     Holds all products we sell
user_product  25,564   Ties users and products together (purchased products)
instructor    47       Holds all instructor information
location      220      Holds all location information
```

The information I need to know for the first 50 rows only is the following:

```
Table         Column                    Relationship With Table "product"
product       product_id             
product       product_name
user_product  Count(user_product_id)    product_id
instructor    instructor_full_name      instructor_id
location      location_name             location_id
```

Note that every product does have a location, but every product may not have an instructor or any user_products tied to it.

The following sql statement works, but it takes a really long time to pull the results.

```
SELECT COUNT(user_product_id) as products_sold, product.product_id, product.product_name, location.location_name, instructor.instructor_full_name 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN instructor ON product.instructor_id = system_instructor.instructor_id 
LEFT JOIN user_product ON product.product_id =  user_product.product
INNER JOIN location ON product.location_id = location.location_id 
GROUP BY product_id 
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Desired Outcome:

```
product_id    product_name     products_sold   instructor_full_name   location_name
1             System Risks     356             Tim Tom                room 1004
2             Planning Ahead   42              Bill Bob               room 2025
```

I suppose the question is is this the most efficient method of pulling this data? Sadly a faster way I've found to run it is pull the count of purchased products row by row as it loops through the query instead of calling one large query

Comment: try adding 'order by null' after the `group` and before the `limit`. otherwise, you need to show the `explain` output for the query. its likely that you don't have necessary indices. also, can a product have more than one instructor or location? if so your query is fundamentally broken, beyond the execution time

Answer (score 0):

Select the COUNT() and the necessary fields from product as a subquery and then do the joins:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM
    ((SELECT COUNT(user_product_id) as products_sold, product_id)
    FROM user_product 
    GROUP BY product_id 
    LIMIT 0, 50) as productsCounted
JOIN product ON product.product_id = productsCounted.product_id) as counted_and_id
    LEFT JOIN instructor ON counted_and_id.instructor_id = system_instructor.instructor_id 
    LEFT JOIN user_product ON product.product_id =  counted_and_id.product_id
    INNER JOIN location ON counted_and_id.location_id = location.location_id ;
```

Otherwise, you're doing the join *before* the aggregation, and generating an enormous table.

Comment: I dont understand how this can work. user_product_id, instructor_full_name, and location_name are not a part of product, That select count by itself would cause an error

Comment: And wouldn't this also only show courses where user_products existed? (May be wrong on this)